# Ubuntu 13 - format drive on server

Tags: ubuntu

I bought server with installed Ubuntu 13. Server have 1TB hard drive but I have only:

```
 /dev/sda1        92G   22G   66G  25% /
```

Company said that this is a standard drive format for Ubuntu instalation and I must add new partition and format it to have more space for my site. How can I do it? I never do something like that and I don't want to accidently format whole data on server.

Comment: you'd probably do best to use `gparted` to create more partitions. Otherwise, `cfdisk` is nice. But already not for (excuse me) newbies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
sudo gparted
```

and use it to enlarge the partition to cover the whole disk. Your sudo password is the one you logged in with.

Comment: so i can enlarge existing partiotion without losing data on it?

Comment: http://gparted.sourceforge.net/ says:With GParted you can resize, copy, and move partitions without data loss. And I did it with success recently :-)